# Sometimes view in MySQL is empty, sometimes is not

Tags: mysql, view

My view in MySQL database has weird behaviour. Very often it works correctly, but rare it returns empty results (no rows) even in other tables have data.
But when I copy-paste the body of the view and try to execute as a simple SQL query, there are existing records!

In the definition of the view I have some UNION statements:

```
CREATE VIEW xyz AS
(
 ...
) UNION (
 ...
) UNION (
 ...
) UNION (
 ...
)
```

What's can be the reason?

Comment: Could the database be changing between you copy & pasting and executing it?

Comment: Nope. The database in development environment, and only I have access to it

Comment: Could the query end up with incorrect syntax in it? It could come from inputs etc although they should be escaped.